# Bootstrap large modal dialog design issue

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a form inside a modal dialog, it's working if I don't identify a modal size, but if I go to this page: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals and copy large size modal dialog code, and put my form inside it, the design will be wrong, and the form will be stuck at the top and right borders.

Here's a JS fiddle of the form itself: https://goo.gl/wsnwm8

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**FORMAT for bootstrap modal**

```
<div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
         <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">Modal Body</div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

`

Enclose your form inside `modal-body` 
like below

`<div class='modal-body'><form ><form></div>`

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/SantoshPandu/tdby8wec/3/)

Comment: That worked.. but why the code in bootstrap large modal snippet (http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals)  didn't mention this?

Comment: Hi Santosh, Yes but why they provided code that needs to be modified as you told me to do?

Comment: @BrittanyRutherford. they provided the code that i said to modify in `Static Example`.  after that they showed how to use large and small modals.  there is no need to write all code every time to explain the different features of something ( here it is modal).

Answer (score 0):

Put a container class in your  `modal-content` and everything will look just right.

```
 <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content container">
           <!-- form content goes here -->
        </div>
</div>
```

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tdby8wec/2/)